# Use java streams to update objects based on a particular check

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

I have a list of objects `testAList` of class `TestA`. I am experimenting Java streams and What I am trying to achieve is update `String b` attribute of all objects from that list that satisfies a check.

```
class TestA {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

So far below is what I have achieved using streams:

```
if(testAList!=null) {
 testAList.forEach(testA -> {
    if(testA.getA().equals("STREAMS") {
       testA.setB("JUST_TEST");
    }
 });
}
```

I am pretty sure that this check can be rewritten in a better way using some predicate but unable to find the right match. I saw `filter` but don't think it could be used as I want the complete source `testAList` back (but with some updates inside the objects).

Any hint would be enough :)

Comment: `replaceAll(x -> if(x.getA().equals("STREAMS") {
       x.setB("JUST_TEST"); return x;
    }; return x;)` Not compiled, but look at `replaceAll`

Comment: Just use a for loop here.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Of course I can. but any particular reason for using a loop? Is it performance? or is it complexity of code?

Comment: basically `list.stream().filter(...).forEach(...)` (filter does not remove elements from the list, kind of only from the stream) and if you have the corresponding methods: `list.stream().filter(TestA::isAStreams).forEach(this::setBJustTest)` (obviously with better names)

Comment: @ManinGreen Since you are mutating the state.

Comment: Streams are neat, but they're generally not more performant than standard loops.  In which case the main goal should be readability.  This is a case where a simple loop is probably going to be easier to read (and thus maintain) than some overly-complex stream concoction.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I started typing my answer before your comment appeared. Gutted that it will now look like I stole your idea!

Comment: @ThomasTimbul it is OK, I just didn't *want* to spend that much time writing an answer [:-)

Comment: filter() actually filters the stream and not the actual array/list. @CarlosHeuberger thanks for this line. Cleared up a lot of things related to the streams. My bad didn't think of it before :) was confusing it with the actual list all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must, you could do:

```
testAList.stream()
         .filter(testA -> "STREAMS".equals(testA.getA()))
         .forEach(a -> a.setB("JUST_TEST"))
         ;
```

As an exercise, you could also create a 'isStreams' method:

```
boolean isStreams(TestA a) {
    return "STREAMS".equals(a.getA());
}

//later
if(testAList!=null) {
    testAList.stream().filter(this::isStreams).forEach(a -> a.setB("JUST_TEST"));
}
```

Going one further:

```
void setBToJustTest(TestA a) {
    a.setB("JUST_TEST");
}

//later
testAList.stream().filter(this::isStreams).forEach(this::setBToJustTest);
```

That would take all the nitty gritty 'neatly' out of the streams expression.

Instead of on "this" you could also declare those statically on a helper and access by method reference for example: `TestAHelper::isStreams`